# Filling a tree bottom up

Tags: java, tree

Basically what I need to do is form a tree-structure from an unsorted list with objects. This tree needs to be filled based on the parentId-attribute of the objects in the list. So if an object in the list has `parentid=0`, it is the root. If it has `parentid=1` , then it is the child of the object with `id =1`. Under 'Filling the tree' is the problem. Now it is statically filled but I need a dynamic way to fill the tree. Hopefully someone can give me some advice.  I have abstracted my problem and made the following code:

```
public class Node {
   private int id,parentid;
    private String text;

    public int getParentid() {
        return parentid;
    }

    public void setParentid(int parentid) {
        this.parentid = parentid;
    }

    Node(int id , String s,int pid){
        setId(id);
        setParentid(pid);
        setText(s);
    }

    public int getNummer() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int nummer) {
        this.id = nummer;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class NodeTreeSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tree");

        //The unsorted list with the objects
        Collection<Node> treeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        treeList.add(new Node(1,"Rootnode",0));
        treeList.add(new Node(2,"Child of node with id 1",1));
        treeList.add(new Node(3, "Child of node with id 1", 1));
        treeList.add(new Node(4, "Child of node with id 2", 2));
        treeList.add(new Node(5, "Child of node with id 2", 2));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        //Filling the tree
        for(Node n:treeList){
            if(n.getParentid()==0){
               root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(n.getText());
            }
            if(n.getParentid()==1){
                root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(n.getText()));
            }
            if(n.getParentid()==2){

            }
        }
        JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a binary tree or a very complicated tree and such you don't need a "dynamic solution" and I guess you don't mean dynamic programming? Anyway what you want is a depth-first search of the tree to insert a new node because this isn't a really complicated tree where you have to split a node.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. So even if there are many objects in the treelist I can fill the tree by using deph-first search?  I meant that the code under filling the tree is not dynamic now because I use an if-structure for each parentid an in my application there are a lot of parentids.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about recursion and depth-first search but it is in php my favorite language: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1235